How can I show homogeneity is preserved after coordinate transformations?
While working on a derivation for a physics result, it turned out to be useful to apply Euler's homogeneous function theorem to rewrite a function in terms of derivatives of its variables. Namely, I have the kinetic energy function $T$ that depends on several velocities $\left\{\dot{q}_j = \frac{d q_j}{dt}\right\}$ defined for generalized coordinates $q_j$. A convenient result of the homogeneous function theorem is that the kinetic energy can be written as,
\begin{gather*} 
2T(\{ \dot{q}_j\}) = \sum_j \dot{q}_j \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q}_j}
\end{gather*}
This result follows from the kinetic energy function being a second degree homogeneous function of its generalized velocities. It is extremely easy to see how the kinetic energy is a second degree homogeneous function of the velocities when using the Cartesian coordinates $\{ x_j \}$ since,
\begin{gather*}
T(\{ \dot{x}_j\}) = \sum_j \frac{1}{2} m_j \dot{x}_j^2 \\
\implies T(\lambda \{ \dot{x}_j\}) = \sum_j \frac{1}{2} m_j (\lambda \dot{x}_j)^2 = \lambda ^2 \sum_j \frac{1}{2} m_j \dot{x}_j^2 = \lambda ^2 T
\end{gather*}
My question is whether there is a straightforward way to show that the order of homogeneity is preserved when transforming the kinetic energy into generalized coordinates. The transformation can be written explicitly in the form,
\begin{gather*}
T = \sum_k \sum_l \frac{1}{2} \dot{q}_k (g^{-1})_{kl} \dot{q}_l \\
(g^{-1})_{kl} = \sum_j m_j \frac{\partial \dot{x}_j}{\partial \dot{q}_k} \frac{\partial \dot{x}_j}{\partial \dot{q}_l} = \sum_j m_j \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial q_k} \frac{\partial x_j}{\partial q_l} 
\end{gather*}
In the equation above $(g^{-1})_{kl}$ are the components of the metric tensor for the transformation between the coordinate systems. My intuition tells me that the metric tensor should be homogeneous of order 0 in the generalized velocities since the relationships between coordinates should not be affected by scaling them, but I am not sure how this could be shown. If this is the case then the second order homogeneity of $T$ would trivially follow as before.

Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/832378/2451
